# OpenCV resize() causes shearing in new image

Tags: opencv

I am resizing a `720 x 480` image to `1920 x 1080` in opencv using the resize command: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize

```
cv::Mat imgA = [self matForPixelBuffer:[self bufferA]]; 
cv::Mat imgB = [self matForPixelBuffer:[self bufferB]]; 
cv::Mat resizeB(imgA.rows, imgA.cols, CV_8UC4);
cv::resize(imgB, resizeB, resizeB.size(), 0, 0, cv::INTER_LINEAR);
```

---

imgA and imgB are 1920x1080 and 720x480 respectively with a buffer of CV_8UC4, that is unsigned chars with a 4 byte stride, GRBA.

When I resize my imgB, the resultant image resizeB is sheared. Would anyone have any suggestions as to what is causing this?

Here is the sheared image: http://pasteboard.co/1XzmTl1l.png

and here is the original: http://pasteboard.co/1XZkSKss.png

Comment: That is wierd, may you post the original image here?

Comment: besides, have you tried to split the image to single-channel images before resize and merge them after.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I discovered an error in my routine:

```
cv::Mat img((int)[pixelBuffer width], (int)[pixelBuffer height], CV_MAKETYPE(CV_8U,(int)[pixelBuffer numberOfBytes]), [pixelBuffer data]);
```

I reversed my rows and cols when constructing my Mat. Once I fixed this, I was able to properly scale my Mat

```
cv::Mat img((int)[pixelBuffer height], (int)[pixelBuffer width], CV_MAKETYPE(CV_8U,(int)[pixelBuffer numberOfBytes]), [pixelBuffer data]);
```

Comment: That would certainly do it :)

Comment: You can construct a Mat in the reverse order and have it still work. In my case I was binding my Mat to an OpenGL texture which made the texture fit the reverse dimensions. The texture was hiding the fact that I improperly specified the dimensions. This only showed up once I resized the Mat.

Comment: Just good to see you got that figured out :) Don't worry, you aren't the only one to mix up rows and cols from time to time.

Comment: Also you don't down vote because an answer is obvious, you down vote if the question is unclear or there was a lack of research, not because of a mistake. There will be others who confuse the rows and columns attributes of an opencv Mat precisely because the terminology is not applicable to the uses Mat are made for. I don't understand why opencv uses rows and columns when all picture and image dimensions are specified at width and height.